# How can I run PySpark on a single node and multiple node Hadoop Environment?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need a one single node and multiple node hadoop environment on docker and i need to make some analysis using PySpark on these hadoop environments. Now i am trying one single node. I pull an ubuntu image, containerized it and installed hadoop environment on this container but i confused whether spark runs on a installed hadoop environment or it needs to install its own environment which has hadoop(Maybe the sentence is complicated, is spark establish on hadoop or is spark install hadoop while its own installation?).

Comment: If you just want to run Spark on a single node then you can just `pip install pyspark`. Only install Hadoop if you want to run over multiple nodes. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html.

Comment: Please put your answer below rather than editing the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved setting up multinode hadoop environment on docker problem using this github repo : https://github.com/rubenafo/docker-spark-cluster and you can look at this article too : https://medium.com/@rubenafo/some-tips-to-run-a-multi-node-hadoop-in-docker-9c7012dd4e26